# epsilon-delta exercise with application

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking for an exercise that tests the understanding of the epsilon-delta definition of continuity, whilst also providing a "nice" application, preferably a number theoretic one.

I'm not sure whether this actually exists though, since the first part is really first principles.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be happy to hear them!

Answer (score 0):

I'll tentatively suggest a classic: proving the (dis)continuity properties of [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). Such a function is continuous at every irrational point, but discontinuous at every rational point. It's a slightly less routine application of the definition of continuity, and has a vaguely number-theoretic flavour.

While I'm sure there are plenty of cooler number-theoretic uses of epsilon-delta limits, I think you're not going to find a better balance between being relatively simple and having a number theory flavour.